# pytoch: RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 14]' is invalid for input of size 491520

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to follow this tutorial [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/transformers-for-multilabel-classification-71a1a0daf5e1): However, When I am trying to train my model. I am getting this.

```
RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 14]' is invalid for input of size 491520
```

here is the line that causes this error:

```
logits = outputs[0]
loss_func = BCEWithLogitsLoss() 
loss = loss_func(logits.view(-1,num_labels),b_labels.type_as(logits).view(-1,num_labels))
```

I have 14 output as you can guess from the error. When I checked the shape of `logits`, I got this `32 * 20 * 768`.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because 491520 is not a multiple of 14.

There is no way for PyTorch to reshape it to `(-1, 14)`.
Make sure your `logits` tensor has a total size that is a multiple of 14.